# What are the recommended font family fallbacks for all browsers on desktop, Android and iOS devices?

Tags: css, font-face, webfonts

I am looking for a combination of sans-serif web-safe fonts to ensure maximum compatibility between all major desktop and mobile browsers like Google Chrome, Firefox, Mi Browser etc without compromising on my page's loading speed.

If I choose Verdana for desktop, should I choose Roboto/Droid Sans for Android and Helvetica Neue for iOS devices?

What should be the ideal fallback font set so that the browser chooses their default font correctly? Also, is using font-family : swap property recommended? Looking forward to any help I can get.

Comment: The page loading speed will only be a problem if you add a font that has to be downloaded. And why is `sans-serif` as fallback not working for you?

Comment: I am currently using Whitney font and planning to let it go. I am looking for a way to make the site look good on bare minimum. So, is there a standard list like: -apple-system,system-ui,BlinkMacSystemFont,Roboto,Helvetica Neue,Ubuntu,Oxygen,Droid Sans,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; that should work on maximum browsers?